# GWT DevMode is not working after Ant compile

Tags: gwt, ant, drag-and-drop, compilation

I'm having trouble after `ant compilation` for specific browser.If i build for all browsers with ant everything is properly working, but if i compile for specific browser `GWT DevMode` is not working until deleting all files from `war`. As you know ant build for all browsers takes very long time.So, deliverability of tasks is very low.
Here is my code: For OrphanWorkspace Module , and I think,I inherited all required things , and `<inherits name='com.allen_sauer.gwt.dnd.gwt-dnd'/>` as well.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<project name="OrphanWorkspace" basedir=".">

 < import file="Base_build.xml"  />

<target name="OrphanWorkspace">
    <antcall target="MAIN">
        <param name="permutation" value="com.site.gwt.orphanworkspace.OrphanWorkspace"/>
    </antcall>
</target>
<target name="OrphanWorkspace_IE6">
    <antcall target="MAIN">
        <param name="permutation" value="com.site.gwt.orphanworkspace.OrphanWorkspace_IE6"/>
    </antcall>
</target>
<target name="OrphanWorkspace_SAFARI">
    <antcall target="MAIN">
        <param name="permutation" value="com.site.gwt.orphanworkspace.OrphanWorkspace_SAFARI"/>
    </antcall>
</target>

<target name="OrphanWorkspace_OPERA">
    <antcall target="MAIN">
        <param name="permutation" value="com.site.gwt.orphanworkspace.OrphanWorkspace_OPERA"/>
    </antcall>
</target>
<target name="OrphanWorkspace_FF3">
    <antcall target="MAIN">
        <param name="permutation" value="com.site.gwt.orphanworkspace.OrphanWorkspace_FF3"/>
    </antcall>
</target>

<target name="OrphanWorkspace_FF2">
    <antcall target="MAIN">
        <param name="permutation" value="com.site.gwt.orphanworkspace.OrphanWorkspace_FF2"/>
    </antcall>
</target>
```

**Base_build.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

   <project name="Base" basedir=".">

    <property name="gwtc.lib" value="..\gwtclib"/>
    <property name="gwt.dir" value="..\war"/>
    <property name="gwtcopt" value=" -XdisableCastChecking  -XdisableClassMetadata"/>
    <property name="soyc" value="-soyc"/>
     <property name="extra" value="-extra out\extra"/>

<path id="gwt.compiler.classpath">
    <pathelement location="${basedir}/src"/>
    <pathelement location="${basedir}/../bmt/src"/>
    <fileset dir="${gwtc.lib}"/>
</path>

<target name="MAIN">
    <echo message="Compiling ${permutation} section"/>

    <java failonerror="true" fork="true" classname="com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler"
          classpathref="gwt.compiler.classpath">
        <arg line="-logLevel INFO -localWorkers 2 -war ${gwt.dir} ${gwtcopt} ${permutation}"/>
        <jvmarg line="-Xmx1024M -Xss32M"/>
    </java>
</target>
```

*And finally I'm getting this* **ERRORS**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would double check that in debug mode you are using the same .gwt.xml (i.e. the one where you specified the user.agent) as the one that Ant built.